# How to disallow multiple outstanding requests on openssh server

Tags: ssh, sftp

The [openssh/sftp client has the ability to configure](https://man.openbsd.org/sftp#R) the max allowable outstanding requests with the `-R` option.

Is there something equivalent on the server side of things?  I have a client that permits multiple outstanding requests and I want to test its behaviour when connecting to a server that does not support or does not allow multiple outstanding requests.  So I'm looking for a way to either disable this functionality on `sshd` or find another server implementation which either doesn't support this feature or allows me to turn it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like misunderstanding.

The OpenSSH *server* reads, processes and responds the requests one-by-one. It does not do any "outstanding" requests. Even if the client "queues" multiple requests, the server won't even recognize it. The requests are simply queued in TCP and SSH pipelines.

If you should be looking for a special server behavior, then it would be an SFTP server that responds to the requests in different order than in which they were received.